# _PS_MODE_DEV_ not working in Prestashop 1.6.1.11

Tags: debugging, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to install/configure a theme in a new/clean Prestashop 1.6.1.11 installation. I was able to install/enable the theme, but when I try to view the page it comes back with a 500 error message.

I changed _PS_MODE_DEV_ to true in /config/defines.inc.php but still I only get:

```
The x.x.x.x page isn’t working
x.x.x.x is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

It's not showing the error debug information so that I can troubleshoot.

Anywhere else where I need to enable this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to delete htacces file?

Comment: Please check your server log to get the reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to view the error even after enabling error debugging because the error is being generated before the error debugging is set to enabled. In order to debug your issues, you can check the error log on your server.

In case of Apache you can check following file:
/var/log/apache2/error.log